# Can Intellij debug javascript code served by a local web server

Tags: javascript, debugging, rest, intellij-idea

I am familiar with using IntelliJ integrated JavaScript debugging to debug JavaScript files.

However, in the web browser the start address is always file-based as in :

```
file:///W:/WORK/JQueryClient/src/index.html
```

I'm working on an application which is making REST calls to my own web server.  So if I start from a file address it won't work because of cross domain issues.  (I can't use JSONP because I will be using PUT and POST in addition to GET , and besides the deployed application will serve up everything from the same domain, I want to code the application identically to the development world).

In Chrome or Firefox I simply get round this by pointing at my web server

```
http://localhost:50036/src/index.html
```

Here the files served up by my web server are  my own local files.

Is there anyway I can configure IntelliJ  to start at local host
 in place of a file address?

Comment: Why are you trying to intellisense a live application? This seems really strange to me. Usually you just intellisense the source code, which lives on disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can - you need using the JavaScript Remote debug configuration, set your `'http://localhost:50036/src/index.html'` as 'URL to open' and specify remote URL mapping for your project folder (usually it's your web server root url + web path on server)
See http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Remote_JavaScript_debugging_with_WebStorm_and_PHPStorm#Installing_and_configuring_Apache_Web_server for more info

Note that as of WebStorm 7 there is only one run configuration for JS debugging, and the run configuration created from right-click menu  (action "Create/Debug" html file) uses the url on built-in http server instead of file url

Comment: Great.  It took me a moment or two to realise I had to scroll down to the' Creating run/debug configuration for 'remote debugging' tag on the webpage you referred me to but once there it is indeed easy. The reason I couldn't find the configuration option was because I was expecting it to be directly below the 'edit configurations' option as it would be in Java.  I notice if I want to restart the debugging session from IntelliJ it always prompts me - is there any way I can restart without a prompt?  After all users may close web browsers without warning.

Comment: I'm not sure what version you are using - the behavior is different in different versions. do you mean 'are you sure you want to stop 'config_name'' dialog? Seems that the only way to get rid of it is checking 'do not show this dialog in the future' checkbox. Note that no such prompts appear on re-running apllication in the most recent versions (WebStorm 7, Idea 13)